# merge large existing web app into Sailjs site

Tags: sails.js

I'm trying to merge large existing web app into `sails.js`. so I moved the folders into assets and build a custom route , `'GET /': '/assets/client/launch.html'` and get **404** when I point my browser to `http://localhost:1337/` as the / is correctly redirected to `http://localhost:1337/assets/client/launch.html` which produces the **404**.

Now the file exists in the folder assets/client (and in .tmp), so I am thinking the Sails router is getting in the way.

I would leave the client (70K lines of JS) that generates all the UI dynamically  and sailjs server that provides authentication separate and enable CORS but my customer wants client packaged with server. This type of operation is simple in frameworks like ASP.NET MVC but am wondering if Sails is up to the task.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If everything you tried did not work out. There might be another solution ,
First of all since you are talking about sails app I am assuming other bundle must be sails as well ,
So here is what you do-
Change the port for another app that you want to attach to this.
Second whenever you want to go to page on another app simply redirect the client to another port ie
in html or esp put a href tag with different port.

```
<a href="localhost:PORT/route_to_file">
</a>
```

Comment: no the other app is a framework developed by my client and they need authentication services .I wanted to use ASP.NET MVC  where this task would be simple but they wanted a solution based on JavaScript. Sailjs seems to provide most of the services of ASP.NET MVC where I would just embed a folder in the server file system. Alas this seems to be a problem with Sails so I guess we sail on

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by placing my app into assets where we need to launch from assets/client/index.html as there would be too many dependencies to change.  As I said above could not just add a route as Sails must getting in the way. However as in Chapter 3.2.2 of Sails in Action I generated a static asset **npm install sails-generate-static --save**. then I redirected to assets/client/index.html. As an aside that book is great and would highly recommend it.